# How Can i Get Output If i have multiple number to match by using only with If else statement and To Get Output If Its Right :- Java Script

Tags: javascript

I want to create a `If else` statement only to match up with `i` `b` `c` text number.

This `i` `b` `c` are just number not a variable. It's only given to compare multiple if statement.
If not matched  it will jump to else and gives output but i don't know how to give multiple if statement ?

like `if i === 21` if  that matched then it goes to next statement i need to create it by if and else statement only.
How can I use multiple if statement ? Like I have done 1 example with only 1 if and else statement

i    b   c

21   23  10

10   34   24

I want to match this 2 rows number i , b , c  number  with only if statement but i need to get output if anyone row matched with the var i , b , c and How can I create multiple if statement to do that.

Here is the example with single if statement

```
var i = 12;

var b = 13;

var c = 04;

if( i >= 21 && b === 23 && c === 10){

console.log("This Is Right Answer");


}else{

console.log("Its Wrong Answer");

}
```

Here is the multiple If Statement

```
var i = 12;

var b = 13;

var c = 04;

if( i === 12 && b === 13 && c === 04){

if( i > 2 && b !== 20 && c === 04){

console.log(" I Is Great ");

}

}else{

console.log("b is greater");

}
```

As in this multiple if statement, if 1st statement is true then it will go to second if, what i am saying is instead of going to second if how can i give console.log and get output.

Comment: Try use nest if? `if(statement 1){ if(statement 2){ } else { statement 2 is false } } else { statement 1 is false }`

Comment: Ok I Got it Ok If 1st Is Right Then i should Get  Output Instead Of Going to Next if Statement , How To Do That

Comment: @BaluMartin If I get it right, use `if-elseif-else`.

Comment: i have Tried  it like Adding If statement on else { if ( i >= 21 && b === 23 && c === 10){

console.log("This Is Right Answer");


}else{
if ( i >= 21 && b === 23 && c === 10){

console.log("This Is Right Answer");



}else{
console.log("Its Wrong Answer");
}  i have tried like this not getting output

Comment: Are you deliberately not using "else if"? `if(statement 1){ } else if(statement 2) {} else {}`

Comment: No Actually i have a Task To Create a statement By Using Only if else This is the note " Your code should include an `if...else` conditional statement "

Comment: With else if its easy to get output but with if else i am confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you well, It sounds like you just need to use **return** in your first if statement.

```
if (...) {
   console.log()
   return
}
```

Comment: Yes Thats Absolute Right But I Only Need To Use If and Else Only To Get Output

Comment: Is it possible for you to save more variables? 
If so you can just save some flag and use it with some if statement

Comment: i Have Finally Used else If Statement Thanks Allot For Helping Me Out